Definition of call/put options
I am reading Essentials of Fincancial Managment, from Jason Laws. From the definition I have, buying a call option gives the buyer the right to buy an asset, let's stay stocks, at a pre-fixed price (plus the premium). Same for a put option on the selling side. However I'm also reading on different websites that neither the seller nor the buyer has to own the stocks in order to exchange options.
How does it work for the buyer ? If the prices went up and you have the right to buy shares way lower than the market price. From whom are you gonna buy ? Who is willing to sell their shares at a lower price ? For me there are finitely many shares available, and people owning these shares decide if they want to sell or not (I'm probably missing something basic).
How does it work for the seller ? If I buy a put option, it gives me the right to sell shares I don't own. When exercising, is the seller obliged to buy the stock at the price market, and sell it at the put strike ?

You might like to read about the difference between physical settlement and cash settlement.  Most options are cash settled so do not involve transfers of the shares themselves.

@Henry, ." all equity (single stock) and ETF options physically deliver when exercised or assigned. See https://www.cboe.com/insights/posts/why-option-settlement-style-matters/

In a nutshell, somebody has sold you the Call option - they don't grow on a tree - and that seller will be forced to procure the underlying asset, for the promised price. The seller got the money you paid for the option, and takes on the corresponding risk. It's his decision - and potential problem - where exactly he gets the shares from; either he owns them upfront, or he is forced to buy them on the market for market price before he gives them to you.
Same for Put options - whoever sells them to you, is responsible for taking the respective asset for the promised price.


If the prices went up and you have the right to buy shares way lower than the market price. From whom are you gonna buy ?

From whoever sold the option.

Who is willing to sell their shares at a lower price ?

By definition, selling a call option means that you are obligated to sell, regardless of how "willing" you are.

For me there are finitely many shares available, and people owning these shares decide if they want to sell or not (I'm probably missing something basic).

If someone sells an uncovered call (that is, they don't own the underlying), and the call gets exercised, then they will have to find someone willing to sell. If no one wants to sell, the issuer of the option will have to keep increasing their bid until someone accepts.

When exercising, is the seller obliged to buy the stock at the price market, and sell it at the put strike ?

Yes, if you want to actually exercise, then you'll need to have the stock. But you can just sell your option to someone who already owns the stock, or is willing to find a share, or who issued a put option and is looking to buy a put back to close out their position.

If someone sells an uncovered call (that is, they don't own the underlying), and the call gets exercised, they 'don't' have to find someone willing to sell. Their intent could be to go short the shares.  The same holds true for the put owner - if he has the account approval and the buying power, he does not have to have the stock to exercise the long put.

@BobBaerker That doesn't make any sense. If you write a call option, and it gets exercised, you HAVE to give the buyer a share. You can't just say "oh, I guess I'm short a share". As for a put owner, if by "account approval", you mean "their broker is willing to let them take the difference", then their broker is just buying the put from them.


It doesn't make any sense to you because you don't understand the mechanics of this. When you short shares, your broker borrows them from an in-house account or from another broker.  You sell them and the broker delivers said shares to your counterparty.  2) "If you write a call option, and it gets exercised, you HAVE to give the buyer a share. You can't just say "oh, I guess I'm short a share".  Technically, it's 100 shares but more relevantly, if your short call is assigned and you don't own the underlying, you are shorting the shares.  Now guess how the broker gets those shares? (see #1)



As for a put owner, if by account approval, you mean "their broker is willing to let them take the difference", then their broker is just buying the put from them." Sorry, but no.  If you exercise a long put and you don't own the underlying, you short the shares (see #1).  4) All of the above assumes that the shares are borrowable.


@BobBaerker Perhaps I should have said "you have to find someone willing to sell or loan a share". My point is that you can't just unilaterally declare that you're going short. You have to find someone with a share that's willing to let you have it. And if you go short, you still have to find someone to sell you a share eventually.

Your understanding of shorting and your explanations are lacking. If I want to short shares, my broker will borrow the shares not I need to find "someone willing to sell a share." The seller is me. Those shares may be in house or borrowed from another brokerage firm. My broker has an indicative list that states how many shares are available for shorting. All I have to do is hit the sell button and the trade is position is executed.  Furthermore, once I am short the shares, when I want to close that position, I BUY shares.  I do not have to "find someone to sell you a share eventually."
